# How to "pair up" existing record to another record on same sObject? NOT Merge

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a custom object for trip registrations. 
I need to pair up the records to make roommates.

So a husband and wife sign up for the trip and two registrations records are added.  Sallie and Sam each have their own record.

Now I want to pair them up as roommates.

I could make a text fields roommate and enter Sam for Sallie's roomie  and Sallie for Sam's roomie.

The problem with that method is that it could lead to typos and there would be 2x the entries.

How can I make a field that would lookup names in the registration finding only those not yet paired.

The user would start typing and the options would change to match the entry.

I have 50 registrations (people) so the first pairing lookup would have 49 names, everyone else but the first name selected to pair.

```
return [SELECT Name, Id , Roommate__c
          FROM lutd_Registration__c  
         WHERE Roommate__c = ''
           AND ID !=  :OwnRecord 
       ];
```

Once paired and on to the next, there would be 47 to pick from and so on going down by 2 every time a pairing was made.  In all 25 pairings would be made in this example.

How can I make this pairing?
I can make a LWC list of all unpaired records with Name and a place to enter a roommate name.  Wht tools would allow me to make it so the user would begin typing the name and a select (or like) window would display matching records as they type, making a selection when Enter is pressed. 
From there I would update the Roommate of both records.
The 
I would like to do this in LWC.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a self relation lookup field (say, Roommate__c  lookup field that looks up the same object i.e. trip registrations)? Since, lookup field are automatically indexed by Salesforce, you could use SOSL in your apex code to do the kind of search you are looking for. This apex code would then have to be wired in your LWC component. My suggestion is based on the assumption that roommate pairing up is going to be exposed via LWC component and that you are expecting only two roommates (i.e. 1 registration record will have only one roommate).

Comment: Why not put both contacts in the same account and link the registration to the account?

Comment: I have not thought about a self relation., it has possibilities. thanks.

Comment: Attaching the roommates to the same room has crossed my mind.